# State machines, encapsulation and OOP design

Tags: oop, fsm

I'm implementing a FSM using [Boost's MSM library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/ch03s02.html).

In the FSM, I have transition tables which describe **Event**s, **Source** states, **Target** states, **Action**s and **Guard**s.

It's my first time using a higher-level design of a state machine. In the past, I've just used switch statments and executed code. However, this one is going to be big and I wanted to keep everything organized properly so it doesn't turn into a mess.

I have an object that represents the state machine (it's a [`boost::msm::back::state_machine<MyStateMachine>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp) where `MyStateMachine` is my implemenmtation which inherits from [`boost::msm::front::state_machine_def`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp) ).

The trick is that my business logic will be done in the **Action**s.  I don't think that's uncommon for a FSM. [Boost's examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/examples/SimpleTutorial.cpp) seems to suggest that these **Actions** should be implemented as methods in the state machine itself, but I'm thinking that this just might make the one class too massive.  I feel it makes sense to separate the work from the state machine.

Which makes more sense to keep a readable, maintainable, and extendable design?

1. Do the business logic in methods in the FSM class (I'm worried that this mixes state management with work too closely).
2. Do the business logic in the parent which instantiates the FSM.  The FSM will need a pointer to the parent, and the parent will need to implement an interface that the FSM understands (that, or the FSM implementation will need to #include the declaration of the parent).
3. Do the business logic in a new class which is instantiated and owned by the FSM.
4. Do the business logic in a new class which is instantiated and owned by the parent, but passed as a reference (or pointer) to the FSM.
5. Something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your situation but I have one approach I usually use.

Maybe it is a variation of the 2 or 5.

Let's say `your_app` has your business logic. And it needs to behave as state-machine. I think that it is one of the typical use-case of the state-machine.

In this case, the state-machine can be placed as the nested class of the `your_app`. `your_app` has the member variable `sm_`, state-machine instance.

The definition of the state-machine is `sm_def`. It has the reference of the `your_app`.

When someone that is outside of the `your_app` want to process an event, call `your_app::process_event()`. If you don't want to provide direct event process interface, you can wrap it as `your_app::handle_some()`. If you do so, `your_app::process_event()` should be private.

Here is example implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>

#include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/functor_row.hpp>

namespace msm = boost::msm;
namespace msmf = boost::msm::front;
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;


// application domain
class your_app {
public:
    your_app() :sm_(boost::ref(*this)) {
        sm_.start(); // start state machine
    }

    // public interface for event processing

    // Event definitions
    struct Event1 {
        int param;
    };

    template <typename Event>
    void process_event(Event const& ev) {
        sm_.process_event(ev);
    }

    void handle_some(int param) {
        process_event(Event1 {param});
    }
private:

    // internal business logic triggered from the state machine
    void do_some_business(int param) {
        std::cout << "do_some_business " << param << std::endl;
    }

    // state machine definiition
    struct sm_def:msmf::state_machine_def<sm_def> {
        sm_def(your_app& ya):ya_(ya) {}
        // States
        struct State1:msmf::state<> {
            template <class Event,class Fsm>
            void on_entry(Event const&, Fsm&) {
                std::cout << "State1::on_entry()" << std::endl;
            }
            template <class Event,class Fsm>
            void on_exit(Event const&, Fsm&) {
                std::cout << "State1::on_exit()" << std::endl;
            }
        };
        struct State2:msmf::state<> {
            template <class Event,class Fsm>
            void on_entry(Event const&, Fsm&) {
                std::cout << "State2::on_entry()" << std::endl;
            }
            template <class Event,class Fsm>
            void on_exit(Event const&, Fsm&) {
                std::cout << "State2::on_exit()" << std::endl;
            }
        };

        // Set initial state
        typedef State1 initial_state;

        // Actions
        struct Action {
            template <class Event, class Fsm, class SourceState, class TargetState>
            void operator()(Event const& e, Fsm& f, SourceState&, TargetState&) const {    
                // get your_app via Fsm.
                f.ya_.do_some_business(e.param);
            }
        };

        // Transition table
        struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
            //          Start   Event   Next    Action  Guard
            msmf::Row < State1, Event1, State2, Action, msmf::none >,
            msmf::Row < State2, Event1, State1, Action, msmf::none >
        > {};

        your_app& ya_;
    };

    friend class sm; // give the friend access to the sm
    typedef msm::back::state_machine<sm_def> sm;

    sm sm_;
};

int main() {
    your_app ya;

    ya.process_event(your_app::Event1{42});
    ya.handle_some(44);
}
```

And running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PQGSGr0bnJHgaMpD